# Confirmation that motherboard is dead

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

all

My computer died yesterday. At first I thought it was the PSU, because it never started, but I tested the PSU with the clip trick and it starts, and I have another PSU that works (for sure), and the computer does not start neither.

I think it's the motherboard (it's a GA-Z170X-Gaming 5-EU). Problem is my case does not have a PC speaker, but the motherboard has a LED to indicate errors. It doesn't show anything. I disconnected everything (even the CPU) and no error at all. The only thing that happens is that the USB connectors in the motherboard are powered, because I have a backlight keyboard, and it's on once I turn the system on. But apart from that, nothing: no fans, no lights from the Motherboard, no error in the led indicator. Nothing. And I disconnected everything: graphics card, RAM, SSD, hard disks, etc... Everything (well, I didn't disconnect USB things, but I don't think that's the issue, I will test it today after work... but if that doesn't fix it neither, I think I can assume the mobo is dead).

The only thing I haven't tried is getting the motherboard out of the PC, because frankly, it would be surprising if the computer has been working for 6 months with no problem and only now I have a short.

So, do you think we can confirm the mobo is dead and that I can proceed with RMA? Or is there anything else I can try?

Cheers,

Comment: Did you try and boot it with one ram stick in? because it will not post at all with no ram installed.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can conclude anything or even rule out a CPU problem.  You should connect a PC speaker to it to get a clear indication if there's an error or not.  Based on what you say, the error indicator probably never came on so it's not very reliable.

Comment: Because there is a LED error indicator that should display the error. It even should display something with no cpu at all. But the issue is that nothing is displayed even when I know it's getting juice from the PSU (backlit keyboard is lit from a USB in the motherboard). I just want to rule out any other possibility unknown to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide more information to complete the answer. The motherboard has come back from RMA. They fixed it by simply clearing the CMOS. It's something I had read, and it was the only thing I didn't do. Clear the CMOS. **So clearing the CMOS (by extracting the battery for 10+ minutes or bridging the adequate jumper) can definitely solve a problem like this one.** "Kudos" for me for not trying this, I wouldn't have wasted money in shipping the motherboard to gigabyte UK (and thanks to them because I had bought the motherboard in a German shop that had gone out of business, and they solved the problem for me).

Comment: Thanks! Although Clijsters answer was also good.

Answer (score 0):

If your PSU works and you checked it with the *clip trick* you can confirm that your Motherboard is broken.

There is always a small residual chance for other things like grounding (case), spordically working capacitors etc. that could work again for some hours, but that can be ignored.

Comment: For older ones, sometimes a B.I.O.S Reset did the trick, but the CMOS times are over...

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be the case's power button has worn out/broke.  Easy test.  Pull off the "power" cable (not the Power LED) from the front panel I/O header on the MB and short the two pins briefly with the flat of a common screwdriver blade or table knife.  If the PC leaps to life replace or rig a new switch. [edit: though now that I think about this, your USB ports not powering on until you push the case's power button says the button is fine.]

If not then I agree, most likely the MB has failed.  To RMA with MB mfg. you will need to contact the Gigabyte Tech Support.  Have everything you tried neatly organized so you do not have to do too much else.

Comment: Yep, the power button was one of the first things I tried. Problem is that I bought the mobo in Germany (I live in Ireland), and there, you have to manage the RMA through the shop (that was hardwareversand, and went out of business after Christmas, lol, although another shop is taking care of that). I have a prospect of one or two months before I get a replacement, or the mobo is fixed.